# Magical method __len__()

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-2.7, arraylist

How to call the `__len__()` function using an object of the class ?

```
class foo(object):
      def __init__(self,data)
         self.data = data
      def __len__(self):
         return len(self.data)
x = foo([1,2,3,4])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea behind a magic method is to be able to call it as `x.__len__()` or `len(x)`. They don't return the output until explicitly called or have or stored in class variables.

#### Method 1: Call function explicitly

You can simply call the function explicitly as -

```
class foo(object):
    def __init__(self,data):
        self.data = data
    def __len__(self):
        print('i am in a magic function')
        return len(self.data)

x = foo([1,2,3,4])
len(x)    #or x.__len__() which is equivalent
```

```
i am in a magic function
4
```

#### Method 2: Display during initialization

Or if you want to trigger it during initialization, just add it in the `__init__()`. Remember, init wouldn't return anything so you can push the output into stdio with a print.

```
class foo(object):
    def __init__(self,data):
        self.data = data
        print(self.__len__())
    def __len__(self):
        print('i am in a magic function')
        return len(self.data)

x = foo([1,2,3,4])
```

```
i am in a magic function
4
```

#### Method 3: Store and access as a class variable

If you want to save it, then you can define a `self.length` variable which can store it and can be retrieved by `x.length`

```
class foo(object):
    def __init__(self,data):
        self.data = data
        self.length = self.__len__()
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.data)

x = foo([1,2,3,4])
x.length
```

```
4
```

Comment: I have added that as my explanation.

Comment: Not sure why the downvote. my explanations and different methods to accessing the return value of the magic functions is accurate.

Comment: You are right, I meant to state that for the case where they are part of the init, as my second and third example. I have made the necessary correction.

Comment: Excellent explanation

Answer (score 2):

You can do it this way:

```
>>>x = foo([1,2,3,4])
>>>len(x)
4
```

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted. It's correct. __len__ is a magic method

Answer (score 0):

### It basically allows you to use `len()`.

Imagine you have only:

```
class foo(object):
    def __init__(self,data):
        self.data = data

x = foo([1,2,3,4])
print(len(x))
```

[image]

---

Now, if you have:

```
class foo(object):
    def __init__(self,data):
        self.data = data
        self.length = len(data)

x = foo([1,2,3,4])
print(len(x))
```

You still have the error:
[image]

(You can get the length with `x.length` though)

---

But if you add the magical method `__len__()`:

```
class foo(object):
    def __init__(self,data):
        self.data = data
        self.length = len(data)

    def __len__(self):
        return self.length

x = foo([1,2,3,4])
print(len(x))
```

You now use `len()` successfully.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Same way you call any other function. By its name.

```
print(x.__len__())
```

which will give 4 for your code

Comment: len() will call __len__() on the object. So the pythonic way is to do `len(x)`

Answer (score -1):

If we go with your class called `foo()` we can call the method `__len__` like this.

```
a =  foo([1,2,3,4])
b = a.__len__()
```

Or if you want to save the length within the class:

```
class foo(object):
    def __init__(self,data)
        self.data = data
        self.len = None
    def __len__(self):
        self.len = len(self.data)     

a = foo([1,2,3,4])
a.__len__()

print(a.len)
```

Comment: Changing the return type of `__len__` kind of defeats the purpose of the magic method and can cause trouble elsewhere, e.g. TypeErrors.

Comment: That's true. I wasn't thinking of it as a magic method, but I should have because of the underscores